# Easier way to test an existing DNN module?

Tags: module, testing, dotnetnuke

Each time I want to test the DotNetNuke module I'm working on, I uninstall it from the DNN website host control panel, I zip my module dev folder, and then I reinstall it from the DNN website.

Is there any faster way to test my module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you testing the *install process*?

If not - all the changes in `DesktopModules/YourModule` or `App_Code/YourModule` will take effect immediately and will be ready for testing (assuming you're using a Website project, and your virtual directory is pointing to your dev. directory)

If you're using the Web Application project - make changes, build, move the files to the virtual directory target folder, then test.

Let me know if this helps.